# For an Android App using Flutter, routing traffic fails across WiFi with Mobile Data active

Tags: android, flutter, networking, mobile, esp32

This question appears multiple times over the years, and very different results are shown. In our case, the WiFi connects to an IoT device with no internet connectivity. Mobile Data should carry Web Traffic to our Website API, but it fails. The lack of Internet on the WiFi may be the key differentiator for this use case.

Our use case: A user attaches to the SSID of an ESP32 as a Gateway. The ESP32 offers an API we use to access IoT services. However, there is no connectivity through the ESP32 to the Internet. Therefore the AndroidOS issues a warning: "no internet connectivity". This is OK, we don't need Internet, we only need to talk to the IoT services via the ESP32 API.

Meanwhile, the AndroidOS separately connects using Mobile Data to the Internet. We want our App to route Internet traffic to the Cloud through this Mobile Data channel. The problem, we do not know how to force our app's Internet Web Traffic through the Mobile Data route.

Our investigation leads us to believe there is no clear definition of how to route traffic over more than one available network method.

Can selective traffic routing be done by an Android App using Native Code? Other solutions point to this (and not all work), but how would this be done in Flutter?

We have read plugins and discussions about:

- Using the WiFi IoT plugin
- Using the connectivity_plus plugin
- How to sense which network you are on, WiFi or Mobile Data
- The differences between Android and iOS and how things work

We've also heard "let the phone maker decide".